# Visualize events on a timeline with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

### Goal

I like to visualize at which positions an event occurred. The data contains a simple counter (`x`) ranging from `1` to `n()` and a column `hit` which is either `x` when the event occurred or `NA` otherwise.

### Data

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(6102023)
dat <- tibble(x = 1:5000) %>%
  mutate(hit = if_else(x %in% sample(n(), round(.2 * n())), "x", NA_character_))
```

### Plot

```r
ggplot(dat) +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = 1, label = if_else(is.na(hit), "", "|"))) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: Rug like plot which shows a "|" character at each position where an event occured]

I am not happy with this visualization:

1. Although there was an event in only 20% of the cases, the timeline looks very dense giving the visual impression that there were by far more events.
2. We are wasting a lot of white space.

So I would need a crisper visualization which helps me to judge whether the events were distributed randomly or whether there was any sort of pattern.

Comment: If using other packages is an option, you might want to check [vistime](https://github.com/shosaco/vistime) (possible outputs include ggplots and [plotly](https://plotly.com/r/gantt/) graphs) or [timevis](https://github.com/daattali/timevis).

Comment: Using `alpha = .1` makes it a bit easier IMO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an attempt, with `alpha` and `geom_segment`:

```r
ggplot(na.omit(dat)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, xend = x, y = 0, yend = 1), color = "red", alpha = .1) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
```

[image]

---

An other option could be to use `geom_histogram` with the share of events per bin; `binwidth` controls the width of the bin along the x axis. With this method, you see clearly that each bin of 100 observations has

```r
ggplot(na.omit(dat)) + aes(x = x) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y = after_stat(count / sum(count))), binwidth = 100, fill = "white", color = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) + 
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I like that the white space is drastically removed and we see that the events are spread all over the timeline. However, I can't help it still looks like we had much more events

Comment: This gave me a great idea, will add it as an answer, but of course you will get the credit :)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could split your data into groups and use `facet_wrap` to visualize the data with a smaller transparency `alpha` like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

dat |>
  mutate(group = ceiling(row_number()/1000)) |>
  ggplot() +
  geom_text(aes(x = x, y = 1, label = if_else(is.na(hit), "", "|")), alpha = 0.1) +
  facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-10-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Also a neat idea +1

Answer (score 2):

@Maël proposed 2 neat ways of how I could display the distribution and based on that I finally went for a combined solution of his solution, using the segments, but cutting their height to the distribution:

```r
fdat <- dat %>%
  mutate(bin = cut(x, seq(-50L, max(x + 50L), by = 100L)),
         n = sum(!is.na(hit))) %>%
  mutate(cnt = sum(!is.na(hit)), .by = bin) %>%
  mutate(freq = cnt / n)

ggplot(na.omit(fdat)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = x, xend = x, y = 0, yend = freq), color = "red", alpha = .1) +
  ## uncomment ot see that the heights correspond to standrad hist heights
  # geom_histogram(aes(x = x, y = after_stat(count / sum(count))), binwidth = 100, fill = "transparent", color = "black") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format()) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image: Events depicted as segments whose height is cut to the cumulative frequency]

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach, plot only the 'hits':

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(6102023)
dat <- tibble(x = 1:5000) %>%
  mutate(hit = if_else(x %in% sample(n(), round(.2 * n())), 1, 0))

ggplot(dat[dat$hit>0,]) + 
  geom_jitter(aes(x=x, y = hit), height = .02) +
  ylim(1.25, 0.75) + theme_minimal()
```

gives
[image]

You can play with the ylim and the height of the jitter to get it closer to your preferred style - for very small jitters it may be better to chose another point style or use alpha (transparency).